# R plot type "b" with text instead of points - Slope graph with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

is there a way in ggplot2 to get the plot type "b"? See example:

```
x <- c(1:5)
y <- x 
plot(x,y,type="b")
```

Ideally, I want to replace the points by their values to have something similar to this famous example:

[image]

EDIT:
Here some sample data (I want to plot each "cat" in a facet with plot type "b"):

```
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5,9),y=c(0.02,0.04,0.07,0.09,0.11,0.13,0.16,0.18,0.2,0.22,0.24,0.27,0.29,0.31,0.33,0.36,0.38,0.4,0.42,0.44,0.47,0.49,0.51,0.53,0.56,0.58,0.6,0.62,0.64,0.67,0.69,0.71,0.73,0.76,0.78,0.8,0.82,0.84,0.87,0.89,0.91,0.93,0.96,0.98,1),cat=rep(paste("a",1:9,sep=""),each=5))
```

Comment: combine geom.segment and geom.text, but why would you use ggplot2 if you can easily do that in the normal plot way?

Comment: because I need some other ggplot facilities that I did not want to mention, concentrating on the essential...

Comment: Some sample data would really help with this problem.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/38895565/7941188

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an experimental grob in gridExtra to implement this in Grid graphics,

```
 library(gridExtra)
 grid.newpage() ; grid.barbed(pch=5)
```

[image]

Comment: @baptiste let's assume I have a plot 'p' already, how can I "add" it to the plot (p+geom_barbed())? I have seen that there is no such function (geom_barbed) yet...

Comment: for some reason I haven't included this line in the package,

`geom_barbed <- GeomBarbed$build_accessor()`

which explains why `geom_barbed` isn't recognised (why `qplot` worked is a mystery to me)

Comment: Sure; however note that the whole package should be revised as it consists of experimental bits-and-pieces that I have not updated regularly. Further, ggplot2 is currently undergoing a complete rewrite, which will make such code redundant.

Comment: @baptiste can you give any link about the rewrite of ggplot2?

Comment: it's split in different packages, see Hadley's github repository

Comment: @baptiste: I find no `GeomBarbed` in ggExtra. Has the package changed?

Comment: @JohnRos ggExtra was an experimental package which I retired long ago; it turns out there is a newer, unrelated project with the same name. I'll edit this answer since it's no longer applicable.

Answer (score 5):

Set up the axes by drawing the plot without any content.

```
plot(x, y, type = "n")
```

Then use `text` to make your data points.

```
text(x, y, labels = y)
```

You can add line segments with `lines`.

```
lines(x, y, col = "grey80")
```

EDIT: Totally failed to clock the mention of ggplot in the question.  Try this.

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
p <- ggplot(dfr, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x, y, label = y)) + 
  geom_line(col = "grey80")
p
```

ANOTHER EDIT: Given your new dataset and request, this is what you need.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~cat)
```

YET ANOTHER EDIT: We're starting to approach a real question.  As in 'how do you make the lines not quite reach the points'.

The short answer is that that isn't a standard way to do this in ggplot2.  The proper way to do this would be to use `geom_segment` and interpolate between your data points.  This is quite a lot of effort however, so I suggest an easier fudge: draw big white circles around your points.  The downside to this is that it makes the gridlines look silly, so you'll have to get rid of those.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
   facet_wrap(~cat) +
   geom_line() + 
   geom_point(size = 5, colour = "white") + 
   geom_point() + 
   opts(panel.background = theme_blank())
```

Comment: @Musa: The question is ambiguous. You ask for `type="b"` which is points and lines, but the picture is text and lines, which is what I gave you.  Ask a better question and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: @Richie: first of all thx for your effort. The question is about having the type "b" in ggplot, at the end it does not matter if it is points and lines or texts and lines. I guess if I have the type, I could replace points with texts quite easily (geom_point->geom_text)

Comment: the last edit corresponds to the plot type "o" and not "b", please have look at http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/images/lines0.png

Comment: Maybe try geom_segment instead?

Comment: Thx Richie. The trick white the white points is brilliant! I knew that I could do it with geom_segment, but as you pointed it out, it is a lot of effort (you need to compute xend and yend manually!). However, I believe that it would be nice to have this in standard in ggplot2 (maybe as a parameter in geom_path?).

Comment: @Richie. Brilliant hack for the plot itself, but do you have any idea how this can be transferred to the legend as well? The white circle does not show in the legend-hence the shape is covered by the line. I second teucer´s request for a geom that would allow type b plots in ggplot2 as well.

Comment: OK-turns out like hackathon. Using a size aesthetic with similar labels and forcing size with the scale_size_manual to be the same worked out quite allright. Especially when also increasing the legend.key.length in theme.

Answer (score 1):

This is now easy with `ggh4x::geom_pointpath`. Set `shape = NA` and add a `geom_text` layer.

```r
library(ggh4x)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:5, each = 5), 
                 y = c(outer(seq(0, .8, .2), seq(0.02, 0.1, 0.02), `+`)),
                 cat = rep(paste0("a", 1:5)))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = cat)) +
  geom_pointpath(aes(group = cat, shape = NA))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hello Tjebo, is there a way on the y-axis to remove the ticks and place the grouping values?

Comment: @GiacomoDB I think this one should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357612/plot-labels-at-ends-of-lines (just adjust the code to make it the beginning )

Comment: Thank you, I fixed also adding a line on the template I found:`df <- df[complete.cases(df), ] `; just before the graph. I realized it was generating many lines with `NA` values.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make great slope graphs is using the package `CGPfunctions`.

```
library(CGPfunctions)
newggslopegraph(newcancer, Year, Survival, Type)
```

You have also many options to choose. You can find a good tutorial here:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/06/creating-slopegraphs-with-r/