# R plot labels outside with lines from points

Tags: r, plot, label

I need to produce automatically a plot where the dots are connected to their labels (which are outside) through a line. Is there a way to do this in R?.
Thanks in advance.

See here an example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4tepdp5j13ot2dd/Example.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you sure that's how you want it done? I cannot think of any automated way to do so, and, well, it's kind of ugly. Why not use colors, shapes, or print the label name next to the dot? All of these options can be automatically generated and, in my opinion, would look better.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the problem is that I have to many points in the plot (more than 5000) and I want to label 10 or so. I tried those options but none of them were fine to me. I will try the two answers below to see which one is the better for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(10)
lab <- sample(1:10, 5)
par(mar = c(5,4,2,5))
plot(x)
p <- par('usr')
# l <- legend(p[2], p[4], legend = round(x[lab], 2), xpd = NA, bty = 'n')
l <- legend(p[2], p[4], legend = sprintf('Label%s', 1:5), xpd = NA, bty = 'n')
segments(lab, x[lab], l$text$x, l$text$y, xpd = NA, col = seq_along(lab))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the plot @Andrés is looking for. From the dropbox, at least how I understood it, it was a scatterplot of x and y, with labels indicating some z. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @AndrewTaylor I dont understand your comment. One could change the labels literally to anything if one so desired

Comment: Sorry, mountain out of molehill, I suppose. I was just stating that given solution did not have a 1:1 match with what I was interpreting out of the linked plot. Which can be either an issue of my misinterpretation of the given problem, or my unnecessary want for an emphasis of exactness over minimal-yet-conducive to answering the problem type code.

Comment: @AndrewTaylor oh I see what you mean. I was just generating some random labels since there weren't any labels given

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly the plot that I want to generate automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @rawr's solution:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
z <- letters[1:10]
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)

lab <- df$z
plot(x,y)
p <- par('usr')
l <- legend(p[2], p[4], legend = lab, xpd = NA, bty = 'n')
segments(df$x, df$y, l$text$x, l$text$y, xpd = NA)
```

[image]

But now let's say that each label has more than 1 x,y pair:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(20)
y <- rnorm(20)
z <- letters[10:1]
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)[order]

lab <- levels(df$z)
plot(x,y)
p <- par('usr')
l <- legend(p[2], p[4], legend =lab, xpd = NA, bty = 'n')
lab_df<-data.frame(x=l$text$x, y=l$text$y, z=lab)
do_seg<-function(i){
  segments(df[df$z==i,]$x, df[df$z==i,]$y, lab_df[lab_df$z==i,]$x, lab_df[lab_df$z==i,]$y, xpd = NA)
}
lapply(lab,do_seg)
```

Gives us:

[image]

Comment: Thank you again, this is very helpful to my. I will play with these commands :)

Comment: See the `directlabels` package as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357612/plot-labels-at-ends-of-lines