# Add text to geom_line in ggplot

Tags: r, text, ggplot2

I am trying to create a line plot for 2 stocks AAPL and FB. **Instead** of adding a **separate legend**, I would like to print the stock symbols along **with the lines**. How can I add geom_text to the following code? 
I appreciate any help you could provide.

```
library (ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('AAPL')
getSymbols('FB')

AAPL = data.frame(AAPL)
FB = data.frame(FB)
p1 = ggplot(AAPL)+geom_line(data=AAPL,aes(as.Date(rownames(AAPL)),AAPL.Adjusted,color="AAPL"))
p2 = p1+geom_line(data=FB,aes(as.Date(rownames(FB)),FB.Adjusted,color="FB"))
p2 + xlab("Year")+ylab("Price")+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="none")
```

Answer (score 17):

This is the sort of plot that is perfect for the `directlabels` package. And it is easier to plot if the data is available in one dataframe.

```
# Data
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('AAPL')
getSymbols('FB')
AAPL = data.frame(AAPL)
FB = data.frame(FB)

# rbind into one dataframe
AAPL$label = "AAPL"
FB$label = "FB"
names = gsub("^FB\\.(.*$)", "\\1", names(FB))
names(AAPL) = names
names(FB) = names
df = rbind(AAPL, FB)


# Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)

# The plot - labels at the beginning and the ends of the lines.
ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(rownames(df)), Adjusted, group = label, colour = label)) +
  geom_line()  +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = 'none')  +    
  geom_dl(aes(label = label), method = list(dl.combine("first.points", "last.points")))
```

A better plot: Increase the space between the end points of the lines and the labels.  See [here](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/) for other options.

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(rownames(df)), Adjusted, group = label, colour = label)) +
   geom_line()  +
   scale_colour_discrete(guide = 'none')  +    
   scale_x_date(expand=c(0.1, 0)) +
   geom_dl(aes(label = label), method = list(dl.trans(x = x + .2), "last.points")) +
   geom_dl(aes(label = label), method = list(dl.trans(x = x - .2), "first.points"))
```

[image]

---

Question is possibly a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357612/plot-labels-at-ends-of-lines/29359816#29359816).

Answer (score 13):

You simply have to add `geom_text` as u said:

Define the `x`, `y` positions, the `label` you want to appear (and the `color`):

[image]

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('AAPL')
getSymbols('FB')

AAPL = data.frame(AAPL)
FB = data.frame(FB)

p1 =     ggplot(AAPL)+geom_line(data=AAPL,aes(as.Date(rownames(AAPL)),AAPL.Adjusted,color="AAPL"))
p2 = p1+geom_line(data=FB,aes(as.Date(rownames(FB)),FB.Adjusted,color="FB"))
p2 + xlab("Year") + ylab("Price")+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="none") +     
geom_text(aes(x = as.Date("2011-06-07"), y = 60, label = "AAPL", color = "AAPL")) + 
geom_text(aes(x = as.Date("2014-10-01"), y = 45, label = "FB", color = "FB"))
```

**EDIT**

If you want to automatically find positions for `x` and `y` in `geom_text`, you will face new problems with overlapping labels if you increase the number of variables. 
Here is a beginning of solution, you might adapt the method to define `x` and `y

```
AAPL$date = rownames(AAPL)
AAPL$var1 = "AAPL"
names(AAPL)[grep("AAPL", names(AAPL))] = gsub("AAPL.", "", names(AAPL)[grep("AAPL", names(AAPL))])
FB$date = rownames(FB)
FB$var1 = "FB"
names(FB)[grep("FB", names(FB))] = gsub("FB.", "", names(FB)[grep("FB", names(FB))])

# bind the 2 data frames
df = rbind(AAPL, FB)

# where do you want the legend to appear
legend = data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = length(unique(df$var1))))
colnames(legend) = c("x_pos" , "y_pos" , "label")
legend$label = unique(df$var1)
legend$x_pos = as.POSIXct(legend$x_pos)

df$date = as.POSIXct(df$date)
for (i in legend$label)
{
  legend$x_pos[legend$label == i] <- as.POSIXct(min(df$date[df$var1 == i]) +
 as.numeric(difftime(max(df$date[df$var1 == i]), min(df$date[df$var1 == i]), units = "sec"))/2)
  legend$y_pos[legend$label == i] <- df$Adjusted[df$date > legend$x_pos[legend$label == i] & df$var1 == i][1]
}

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.POSIXct(date), y = Adjusted, color = var1)) +
geom_line() + xlab("Year") + ylab("Price") + 
geom_text(data = legend, aes(x = x_pos, y = y_pos, label = label, color = label, hjust = -1, vjust = 1)) 
+ guides(color = F)
```

[image]

Comment: bVa, Thank you for the suggestion. It will work. However, I am looking for a way to print the text with the lines without specifying the x,y coordinates.  When I add more stocks or generate more charts, it becomes a bit tedious to find/add the coordinates.

Comment: You will face new problems: overlapping text. See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you bVa for suggesting another solution. I agree that, as you stated, it will make the solution more complicated. I would like to keep it simple. I appreciate your help.