# Plot labels at ends of lines on left-hand side

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359816/7114709), which provides the solution for the right-hand side.

I need to switch the labels to the opposite side because my curves merge, but they get clipped in spite of the "code to turn off clipping". 
[image]
(Sorry about the padding, this is an unintended consequence of controlling the aspect ratio.)

Here's the code for the chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(temp, aes(x=year, y=value/10^6, group=variable)) + geom_point(shape=1, size=2) + geom_line(size=1) + 
  geom_text(data=temp[temp$year==min(temp$year),], aes(label=c("MSA 2012", "MSA en cours"), x=year-.25, y=value/10^6), 
            hjust = 1, size=4.6) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2001,2015,2)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(95,105,5), position="right") + 
  labs(x="Année", y="Emploi (millions)") + 
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.background=element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), legend.position="top", legend.direction="horizontal", 
        axis.text = element_text(color="black", size=13), axis.title = element_text(color="black", size=13),
        aspect.ratio=.25)
# Code to turn off clipping
library(grid)
gt <- ggplotGrob(p)
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

Comment: Can you use `scale_x_continuous(..., expand=c(0.1,0))` or some similar multiplicative or additive expansion?

Comment: With a theme like this I would also just expand the plotting region instead of dealing with clipping. Either increase `expand` or use `expand_limits`.

Comment: Note that your example isn't reproducible for us so you're unlikely to get exact answers.

Comment: you can also try the `directlabels` package, it is more handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to modify the layout of the gtable associated to the `p` plot.

```
# Generate a toy dataset
set.seed(123)
temp = data.frame(year=rep(2001:2015,2), value=cumsum(rnorm(30)), variable=rep(c("A","B"),each=15))
library(scales)
temp$value <- rescale(temp$value, to=c(95*10^6,105*10^6))  


library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(temp, aes(x=year, y=value/10^6, group=variable)) + geom_point(shape=1, size=2) + geom_line(size=1) + 
  geom_text(data=temp[temp$year==min(temp$year),], aes(label=c("MSA 2012", "MSA en cours"), x=year-.25, y=value/10^6), 
            hjust = 1, size=4.6) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2001,2015,2)) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(95,105,5), position="right") + 
  labs(x="Année", y="Emploi (millions)") + 
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), panel.grid.minor=element_blank(), panel.background=element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), legend.position="top", legend.direction="horizontal", 
        axis.text = element_text(color="black", size=13), axis.title = element_text(color="black", size=13),
        aspect.ratio=.25)

library(grid)
gt <- ggplotGrob(p)
### Modify the layout of the gtable
gt$widths[[2]] <- unit(2.5, "cm")
###
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]