# Plot labels at ends of lines in stacked area chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, stacked-area-chart

I have the following code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# create data
time <- as.numeric(rep(seq(1,7),each=7))  # x Axis
value <- runif(49, 10, 100)               # y Axis
group <- rep(LETTERS[1:7],times=7)        # group, one shape per group
data <- data.frame(time, value, group)

# stacked area chart
ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=group)) + 
  geom_area()+
  geom_text(data = data %>% filter(time == last(time)), aes(label = group, 
                                                               x = time + 0.5, 
                                                               y = value, 
                                                               color = group)) + 
  guides(color = FALSE) + theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(10))
```

Where i get[image]

But i am aiming for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51139883/10595361)

Is there any solution for stacked area plot?

Comment: Does adding `position = position_stack(vjust = 1)` inside `geom_text()` achieve your desired look?

Comment: @Z.Lin Got an error connected with infinite loading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question code is plotting the text labels in the `value`'s of the last `time`, when in fact the areas are cumulative. And in reverse order.

Also, the following graph plots data created with the same code but with

```
set.seed(1234)
```

Then the data creation code is the same as in the question.

```
# stacked area chart
ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=group)) + 
  geom_area()+
  geom_text(data = data %>% 
              filter(time == last(time)) %>%
              mutate(value = cumsum(rev(value))), 
            aes(label = rev(group), 
                x = time + 0.5, 
                y = value, 
                color = rev(group))) + 
  guides(color = FALSE) + theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(10))
```

[image]

**Edit.**

Following the discussion in the comments to this answer, I have decided to post code based on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645609/plot-labels-at-ends-of-lines-in-stacked-area-chart/58645884#comment103599013_58645884) by user [Jake Kaupp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3961477/jake-kaupp).

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = value, fill = group)) + 
  geom_area()+
  geom_text(data = data %>% filter(time == last(time)),
            aes(x = time + 0.5, y = value, 
                label = rev(group), color = rev(group)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  guides(color = FALSE) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(10))
```

Comment: You can just use `position = position_stack()`, which makes the `mutate` and `rev` calls unnecessary.

Comment: @JakeKaupp Thanks. That should be an answer.

Comment: @JakeKaupp did you mean something like this `(data = data %>% 
              filter(time == last(time)) %>%
              # mutate(value = cumsum(rev(value))), 
            aes(label = (group), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
                x = time + 0.5, 
                y = value, 
                color = rev(group)))`

Comment: @MaksymMoroz I have edited the question with that suggestion.

Comment: @RuiBarradas But i should say that  `position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))` doesn't work propely with for example `set.seed(342)` , this whai i've got [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTmlh.png)

Comment: @MaksymMoroz What about mine, does it work? As for `position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))`, you will probably have to ajust the value of `vjust`, that's what I did.

Comment: @RuiBarradas yours - yes but man it can't work for one values and not for others. As i far as i understood it place letters on average level of values they represent but it is needed them to be depended on last time values. There is something wrong with `data = data %>% filter(time == last(time)),`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text` function to put text wherever you want. For example:

```
text(7.2, 350, "B", col="brown")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go

```
time <- as.numeric(rep(seq(1,7),each=8))  # x Axis
value <- runif(56, 10, 100)               # y Axis
group <- rep(LETTERS[1:8],times=7)        # group, one shape per group
data <- data.frame(time, value, group)
round_df <- function(x, digits) {
  # round all numeric variables
  # x: data frame 
  # digits: number of digits to round
  numeric_columns <- sapply(x, mode) == 'numeric'
  x[numeric_columns] <-  round(x[numeric_columns], digits)
  x
}

data$value<- round_df(data$value, 2)
# stacked area chart
ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=group)) + 
  geom_area()+
  geom_text(aes(x = time + 0.5, y = value, label=ifelse(time == max(time), group, NA)),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),check_overlap = TRUE)+
  guides(color = FALSE) + theme_bw()+ 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(10)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(time != min(time) & time != max(time),value, NA)),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),check_overlap = TRUE)+
  geom_text(aes(x = time + 0.18,label=ifelse(time == min(time),value, NA)),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),check_overlap = TRUE)+
  geom_text(aes(x = time - 0.18,label=ifelse(time == max(time),value, NA)),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),check_overlap = TRUE)
```

And get [image]

Factor levels but why not letters? That is the next step :)

**UPDATED**

just converted factor to char `data$group <- as.character(data$group)`
[image]