# Make facet labels horizontal in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet

I want the names on the right hand side labels of the facet plot to be horizontally so they are not cut off. For example, so it reads North England, East Midlands, etc.

[image: Image here:]

Comment: Please [edit as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) Is there any reason you want to use `facet_*` to achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure if `horizontal` is clear !!! But for *cut off*, a solution would be to use `stringr::str_wrap` for text wrapping.

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It should be [minimal, but complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question should be clear and specific. I posted an answer. Hopefully it works for your dataset; but if you post a **minimal** and **reproducible** example of your data (not all of it, remember), then we can be sure that we've been helpful.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357612/plot-labels-at-ends-of-lines for another visualisation option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0)` to rotate the facet strips on the right. I am using `iris` dataset to make a reproducible example.

```r
library(ggplot2)

    ggplot() +
      geom_line(data= iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width, 
                                colour = Species), stat = "identity") +
      facet_wrap(Species ~ ., strip.position = "right", ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
            legend.position = "none")
```

[image]