# How to add labels to multiple curves on ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm trying to add the curves name to my ggplot directly from the legend.

Here's my code

```
plott = ggplot(PL2, aes(P, growth.rate2020, color=Country, showlabels=TRUE)) + 
    geom_point()
```

What I want to see is the name of each country next to each curve

[image]

Comment: Are you searching for something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357612/plot-labels-at-ends-of-lines ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `geom_label` and remove the legend guide:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(
    data = iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(across(everything(), mean)),
    mapping = aes(label = Species, x = 5)
  ) +
  guides(color = FALSE)
#> Warning: `guides(<scale> = FALSE)` is deprecated. Please use `guides(<scale> =
#> "none")` instead.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>