# How do I add the names of the graphs inside the plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, stat, geom

[image]I built the graph but I try to add the names of the graphs and it does not work. It should look like in the picture, I only have the graphs without the names

I would happy if anyone knows which function should be used

Comment: Please make the question reproducible: [MRE]

Comment: Have you looked at ggrepel or directlabels packages?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357612/plot-labels-at-ends-of-lines

Comment: Currently, it is very difficult to help you based on the extremely limited information you have provided. Please see the above-referenced link to provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

The geomtextpath package looks as if it is ideal for this use case. Very nice it is too.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)


ggplot(data.frame(x = 0)) +
  geom_textpath(stat = "function", fun = ~ 2.5 * .x,
                label = "Holding Cost",
                vjust = 1.1, colour = "green", hjust = 0.95, size = 6) +
  geom_textpath(stat = "function", fun = ~ 500 / .x ^0.5,
                label = "Set Up Cost",
                vjust = -0.1, colour = "blue", hjust = 0.95, size = 6) +
  geom_textpath(stat = "function", fun = ~ 500 / .x ^0.5 + 2.5 * .x,
                label = "Total Cost",
                vjust = -0.1, colour = "red", hjust = 0.95, size = 6) +
  xlim(1, 100)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>