# dplyr mutate only works once

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to add a new variable to a dataframe for plotting labels, as seen in the top voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357612/plot-labels-at-ends-of-lines)

Here's the data:

```
small  <- structure(list(Site = structure(c(1L, 20L, 20L, 6L, 18L, 7L, 
8L, 4L, 6L, 20L, 15L, 8L, 14L, 3L, 20L, 4L, 20L, 1L, 15L, 18L, 
15L, 1L, 15L, 11L, 20L, 20L, 16L, 4L, 14L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 
14L, 4L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 18L, 15L, 14L, 4L, 20L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 15L, 
7L, 20L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 14L, 20L, 12L, 
6L, 5L, 20L, 4L, 8L, 20L, 4L, 4L, 15L, 6L, 5L, 20L, 14L, 13L, 
8L, 20L, 14L, 20L, 8L, 3L, 18L, 6L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 
4L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 14L, 15L), .Label = c("1305", 
"1307", "1308", "1309", "1312", "1313", "1314", "1316", "1454", 
"1455", "1456", "1457", "1458", "1459", "1461", "1462", "51242", 
"735", "739", "cc82"), class = "factor"), Sample = c(807001, 
549001, 1776001, 708001, 1428001, 144001, 273001, 2031001, 186001, 
4449001, 495001, 1, 75001, 1395001, 801001, 393001, 48001, 186001, 
633001, 252001, 1047001, 780001, 1149001, 123001, 1803001, 1920001, 
93001, 1539001, 1278001, 252001, 129001, 2415001, 4839001, 222001, 
798001, 2709001, 1350001, 2763001, 2367001, 852001, 1239001, 
1344001, 2364001, 3141001, 1383001, 4284001, 213001, 696001, 
198001, 4521001, 156001, 822001, 1056001, 753001, 48001, 678001, 
132001, 189001, 2958001, 951001, 351001, 183001, 726001, 939001, 
942001, 3144001, 393001, 2559001, 1230001, 3507001, 825001, 1314001, 
525001, 2643001, 1080001, 48001, 657001, 129001, 219001, 2853001, 
27001, 1002001, 372001, 1197001, 183001, 546001, 3189001, 1191001, 
225001, 4173001, 66001, 687001, 882001, 453001, 771001, 1749001, 
39001, 579001, 837001, 2130001), Species = c(1034.99999063637, 
1034.38745958467, 1034.93602944106, 1034.86617039632, 1034.99994688683, 
1031.33494747455, 1034.01286119925, 1034.93820951036, 1034.04207802324, 
1034.99999978378, 1034.7195310584, 1.0000000000006, 1032.22721814454, 
1034.99998599318, 1034.61810976437, 1033.93049848926, 1029.76888222768, 
1034.4773467232, 1034.8464918186, 1033.88103519209, 1034.98062874486, 
1034.99997102765, 1034.9894164954, 1031.22209052865, 1034.9393924588, 
1034.95228329769, 1029.57766168241, 1034.84617251106, 1034.99716319884, 
1034.01759652049, 1034.12421865692, 1034.97165766244, 1034.99999931756, 
1032.5264160899, 1034.9302506075, 1034.9852789914, 1034.99732449456, 
1034.99393176586, 1034.98256074378, 1034.82915901302, 1034.99407894687, 
1034.99848385292, 1034.96842702321, 1034.9982024792, 1034.99990895745, 
1034.99994016069, 1033.46577496826, 1034.8847185144, 1032.07439991374, 
1034.99999994015, 1034.37061686683, 1033.9995317372, 1034.98014310935, 
1034.7765851292, 1023.56493233315, 1034.87292826712, 1033.5159578377, 
1033.67572213954, 1034.99198243374, 1034.97016563294, 1034.08306140893, 
1024.75667862308, 1034.87575799201, 1033.99992196217, 1034.70367833352, 
1034.99510596938, 1034.31114418187, 1034.9893038116, 1034.73597419662, 
1034.99835620314, 1034.93758219921, 1034.99920511546, 1033.98476342599, 
1034.99147574006, 1034.98682314168, 990.598200299325, 1034.72635751567, 
1033.22853472628, 1034.07153177872, 1034.99535891042, 1020.83157812414, 
1034.91858260823, 1034.25487458056, 1034.99478390852, 1033.10757669472, 
1033.94643834015, 1034.99848918266, 1034, 1033.75393660622, 1034.99989098177, 
1032.40178509791, 1034.75797238777, 1034.52419010051, 1034.97051191563, 
1034.8976530452, 1034.89479904612, 1019.98410325148, 1034.78158579658, 
1034.94325878046, 1035)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

The `new` df should contain a 4th column called `lab`, with the `Site` value in it if that row had the highest `Sample` value, otherwise it should be empty:

```
  new = small %>%  
mutate(lab = if_else(Sample == max(Sample), as.character(Site), NA_character_))
```

Instead, only the highest Sample for the `1309` site value has a `lab` entry. There should be one `lab` entry for every highest `Site`. The `Site` variable is a factor.

This image is an example that works from the [link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357612/plot-labels-at-ends-of-lines), where there is one label entry for each state with the highest year:

[image: one label entry for each state with the highest year]

This is the toy data from that question where grouping was not required:

```
temp.dat <- structure(list(Year = c("2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", 
                                    "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2003", 
                                    "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
                                    "2012", "2013", "2014", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", 
                                    "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2003", 
                                    "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", 
                                    "2012", "2013", "2014"), State = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("VIC", 
                                                                                                                                             "NSW", "QLD", "WA"), class = "factor"), Capex = c(5.35641472365348, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               5.76523240652641, 5.24727577535625, 5.57988239709746, 5.14246402568366, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               4.96786288162828, 5.493190785287, 6.08500616799372, 6.5092228474591, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               7.03813541623157, 8.34736513875897, 9.04992300432169, 7.15830329914056, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               7.21247045701994, 7.81373928617117, 7.76610217197542, 7.9744994967006, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               7.93734452080786, 8.29289899132255, 7.85222269563982, 8.12683746325074, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               8.61903784301649, 9.7904327253813, 9.75021175267288, 8.2950673974226, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               6.6272705639724, 6.50170524635367, 6.15609626379471, 6.43799637295979, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               6.9869551384028, 8.36305663640294, 8.31382617231745, 8.65409824343971, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               9.70529678167458, 11.3102788081848, 11.8696420977237, 6.77937303542605, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               5.51242844820827, 5.35789621712839, 4.38699327451101, 4.4925792218211, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               4.29934654081527, 4.54639175257732, 4.70040615159951, 5.04056109514957, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               5.49921208937735, 5.96590909090909, 6.18700407463007)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -48L), .Names = c("Year", "State", "Capex"))
```

And running this correctly assigns the state to the max(year) without grouping as seen in the screenshot:

```
temp.dat %>%
  mutate(label = if_else(Year == max(Year), as.character(State), NA_character_))
```

Comment: If you want this done for every site, you need to put `group_by(Site)` before the mutate. `small %>% group_by(Site) %>% mutate(...` (or State or Year... I can't really tell which column you're trying to group by, but it sounds like you want this done by group, so you need to tell `dplyr` which column to group by).

Comment: That did the trick! If you make it an answer I'll accept it. Do you know why grouping wasn't required for the other question I linked to? I added the toy data for it.

Comment: In the other question, you want to label the max year. Every site has the same max year. The global max is the same as the group max in every group, so no grouping is needed. (Though grouping wouldn't hurt anything.) Here, every site has a different max sample and only one site has the global max sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this done for every Site, you need to put `group_by(Site)` before the `mutate`.

```
small %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  mutate(lab = if_else(Sample == max(Sample), as.character(Site), NA_character_))
```

In the other question, you want to label the max year. Every site has the same max year, 2014. The global max is the same as the group max in every group, so no grouping is needed. (Though grouping wouldn't hurt anything and would make the code more robust in case some site *didn't* have the same max year.)

Here, every site has a different max sample and only one site has the global max sample. If you want the max sample by site, you need `group_by(Site)`.

Comment: The global max thing makes sense. Thanks Gregor.