# Plot 'type = b' in ggplot with geom_segment - adjusting parameters to axis ratio

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are a few questions around how to create a 'type = b' look with ggplot (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810927/getting-r-plot-type-b) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895565/is-it-possible-to-achieve-base-r-plot-type-b-functionality-in-ggplot2))
The currently best solution is simply creating bigger dots in the color of the underlying background - **which is admittedly very straight forward**.
I am looking for a solution with `geom_segment` - because the current solution does not allow for additional 'fanciness', in particular: error bands. See graph at the bottom. (*I know that I can use lines for the confidence intervals, and this looks good, but the question is regarding the below*)

I have made a simple function using basic trigonometry in order to calculate x and y for the segments in `geom_segment` (see below - thanks to @moody_mudskipper to give the main ideas how to approach this). Now, **this only works with `coord_equal`** (see below). My question is, how can I obtain the axis ratio from the plot which is created in order to use this ratio for calculation of the x/y segments?

```r
library(ggplot2)

# function to get data frame with x and y parameters for geom_segment

get_segments <- function(df, x, y, param){
  # hyp = hypotenuse of right triangle between x and y of dot plot
  # sin_plot and cos_plot = sine and cosine of right triangle of dot plot 
  # diff_..._seg  = hypotenuse of segment added to main dot plot 

x <- df[[deparse(substitute(x))]]
y <- df[[deparse(substitute(y))]]
hyp <-sqrt(diff(x)^2 + diff(y)^2)
sin_plot <- diff(y) / hyp 
cos_plot <- diff(x) / hyp

diff_x1_seg <- param * cos_plot
diff_x2_seg <- (hyp-param) * cos_plot
diff_y1_seg <- param * sin_plot
diff_y2_seg <- (hyp-param) * sin_plot

x1 <- c(head(x,-1) + diff_x1_seg)
x2 <- c(head(x,-1) + diff_x2_seg)
y1 <- c(head(y,-1) + diff_y1_seg)
y2 <- c(head(y,-1) + diff_y2_seg)

plot_data <- data.frame(x1,x2,y1,y2)
plot_data$x1 <- ifelse(plot_data$x1 > plot_data$x2, NA, x1)

plot_data
}

# Using the function on sample data 

plot_data <- 
  get_segments(pressure, x = temperature, y = pressure, 15)

# Making the plot 

p1 <- ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(data = plot_data, mapping = aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = y1, yend = y2))
```

**Plot without `coord_equal`** - does not really work

```r
p1
#> Warning: Removed 11 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

**Plot with `coord_equal`** - gives the right segments

```r
p1 + coord_equal()
#> Warning: Removed 11 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

**Example what could be nice:**

```r
ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) + 
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = pressure - 50, ymax = pressure + 50), alpha = 0.2)  +
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(data = plot_data, mapping = aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = y1, yend = y2)) 
#> Warning: Removed 11 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

P.S. I know that I could just plot the ribbon above the plot, but this gets less nice when using different grey values. And again, this question is more about how to get the axis ratio...

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, unless you manually set the axis ratio with for example `theme(aspect.ratio ...)`, or `coord_fixed()` you can't, since the plots adjust their positioning based on the size of the device.

To check this, you can make your plot into a gtable by `ggplotGrob(myplot)` and look at the layout what graphical object is the panel.

```
g <- ggplot(pressure, aes(temperature, pressure)) +
  geom_point()

grobs <- ggplotGrob(g)
```

In that layout you can see the t (top) and l (left) position of the panel.

```
head(grobs$layout)
```

```
   t l  b r z clip       name
18 1 1 12 9 0   on background
1  6 4  6 4 5  off     spacer
2  7 4  7 4 7  off     axis-l
3  8 4  8 4 3  off     spacer
4  6 5  6 5 6  off     axis-t
5  7 5  7 5 1   on      panel
```

You can see above that the panel is the sixth grob in the list and has position 7 of the heights and position 5 of the widths.

```
grobs$widths[5]
```

```
[1] 1null
```

```
grobs$heights[7]
```

```
[1] 1null
```

The height and width of panels are usually defined in `null` units, which is a special unit that kind of tells the graphics device to calculate all other elements first and use the leftover space to place the `null`-sized graphical elements.

Furthermore, the plot has a `respect` parameter that tells the graphics device wether the ratio between `null` units should be 1:1 or are free. This parameters is set to true when there is a known aspect ratio, or by `facet_grid(space = ..., scale = ...)` parameters. If `respect == TRUE`, then a grob with a height of `2null` and a width of `1null` will have an aspect ratio of 2.

```
grobs$respect
```

```
[1] FALSE
```

I don't want to leave you with all bad news so I'm gonna point out that you can also use these widths and heights in the gtable to set them to your liking.

```
grobs$widths[5]  <- unit(2, "cm")
grobs$heights[7] <- unit(5, "cm")
grid.newpage(); grid.draw(grobs)
```

[image]

Which could help you plot the perfect `type = b` style plots.

Off-topic but tangentially related, back at your previous question I also had a go at making the geometric interpretation of the plot (wasn't succesfull so didn't post it), without the point over point trick. I also had a lot of trouble with the aspect ratio, since the exact placing of the points changed on the device size. Under the hood, the grid package that makes graphical objects  (grobs) by default use normalised parent coordinates (npc, see `?unit`). A thing that seemed to be pointing in the right direction was converting what you named `hyp - param` with the equivalent of `unit(hyp, "npc") - convertUnit(unit(param, "mm"), "npc", axisFrom = "y", typeFrom = "dimension")` (for the y-axis, I was already working with `npc` units for my coordinates). Now I wasn't able to implement this properly, but maybe it would help you get some ideas.

Comment: thanks for the long answer and thoughts. the idea with converting units is interesting. I find it just curious (as maybe do many who don’t have such a deep understanding of the underlying mechanics of the plotting) that something so easily done by base R does not have its easy equivalent in ggplot - and I think there must be a way to adjust trigonometry calculations etc to the device size

Comment: I think I may have found a way, involving some wierd stuff. Still coding though, I'll report back.

Comment: I've posted another answer to your previous question, as this question is about aspect ratios and not directly about implementing the `type = b` geometry.